# how can I use coffeescript with jquery?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, koala

I am using the 'Koala' program for CoffeeScript. I will write a coffescript with jQuery. I am writing the following code. Not working

```
$ ->
```

Output code

```
(Function () {
        $ (function () {});
    }). Call (this);
```

This does not work in SW. Do I make a mistake? Or how can I use coffeescript with jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Here's an example…

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <body>
    <a class='button' href='#'>Click Me</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

### CoffeeScript

```
$ ->
  $('.button').click (event) ->
    console.log 'button clicked'
```

[Click here for live example](http://jsbin.com/sotidetada/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Thank you. It was very helpful